# Best practises around GitHub Apps if someone changes their username?

Tags: sql, postgresql, github-api

I am currently building a community around a GitHub app. People sign in with OAuth, and then they can "follow" other people.

However, in my database, I am only storing the numeric GitHub ID of the user, and not the GitHub username.

And if I want to display the GitHub username in the UI of people followed, I'd need to contact the GitHub API with the given GitHub user IDs.

If the list of users to fetch names for is long, that'd quickly exhaust my rate limits.

**My question is:** If I need to display the usernames of my users in a list, is it good practise to store the GitHub username in the database as well? And if that is the case, what happens if the GitHub user changes his/her username? How do I "listen" to that change and update the entry in my database as well?

Comment: I would store the username in the database, and check it from time to time through the API when the user is performing another operation. You could also create a specific service in your APP to allow users to synchronize their datas whenever they want.

Comment: I would store the username and once in a while do a MERGE statement to update your local database with the new information if the user changed its name